# Submit a form multiple times in loop

Tags: php, forms

How can I submit a form multiple times in a loop.

What I am trying to do is to post post data to some 3rd party API for SMS. Now this 3rd Party SMS gateway takes only 50 no. in one go and I have more than 50 mobile no.

```
for (int jj=0;jj<=5; jj++)
{
%>

<form name="f" id="ff" action=http://smswebsite.com/api.php  >

<input type=text name=username value="amu" > 

<input type=text name=password value="password" >

<input type=text name=source value="SenderID">

<input type=text name=dmobile value="917417010049" >

<input type=text name=message value="Testing All from hashmi, malik hayat"  > 

</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
      document.getElementById("ff").submit();
    </script>
<%
}
%>
```

Please help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29337670/how-to-submit-a-single-form-value-multiple-times-and-store-preserve-them-in-an

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the issue you are having????
3 problems I see

1. If a first time form is submitted the page will navigate away. so the next form may not get turn to be submitted.
2. I have noticed your form id remains the same, so there will be multiple forms with same id each time a loop is executed. append the jj counter value with form tag for id `"ff"+jj` and with javascript `getElementById("ff"+jj)`. 
   Use ajax to post the form to so that your page may not navigate away.
3. Call ajax post when document read event is executed: because you might be submitting a form where as the page may not have been rendered yet.

   $( document ).ready(function() {
       // code to submit form through ajax
   });

Answer (score 0):

You can post it as an array.

```
<form name="f" id="ff" action=http://smswebsite.com/api.php  >
for (int jj=0;jj<=5; jj++)
{
%>
<input type=text name="username[]" value="amu" > 

<input type=text name="password[]" value="password" >

<input type=text name="source[]" value="SenderID">

<input type=text name="dmobile[]" value="917417010049" >

<input type=text name="message[]" value="Testing All from hashmi, malik hayat"  > 
<%
}
%>

</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
      document.getElementById("ff").submit();
    </script>
```