# How to submit a single form value multiple times and store (preserve) them in an array each time that I refresh my page?

Tags: php, html, arrays, session, multidimensional-array

Attempt 1: This shows what I want to achieve. The same array but different key and value pair.When printed, it list out all the keys and values.

```
<?php

$rental[]=array('day'=>1,'rate'=>10);
$rental[]=array('day'=>2,'rate'=>20);
$rental[]=array('day'=>3,'rate'=>30);
$rental[]=array('day'=>4,'rate'=>40);
print_r($rental);
?>
```

Attempt 2: Now, I'm using a single form to submit multiple times.I expect the key and values to be stored inside an array each time the form is submitted. But what happens is, the last value pair overwrites the previous one.Therefore only one pair is shown. So far, I can store them with the help of session. But I just wonder if there's a way to achieve it via php array on the same page?

```
<?php

$rental[]=array('day'=>$_POST['days'],'rate'=>$_POST['rental']);

print_r($rental);
?>
<form action="#" method="post">
   Number of Days: <input type="text" name="days" value=""><br/>
   Rental rate: <input type="text" name="rental" value=""><br/>
   <input type="submit" name="add_rental_rate" value="Add Rental Rate">
</form>
```

Comment: Once the form is operational, PHP is not readily available. But JavaScript is.

Comment: PHP processes date for outputting, PHP don't do storing data. You can either done it by JavaScript or store them into Database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use session to achieve what you want, see this code:

```
<?php  
session_start();

if(isset($_POST['days']) && isset($_POST['rental'])){        

$_SESSION['info'][] = array($_POST['days'] => $_POST['rental']);

}

if(isset($_SESSION['info'])) {
for($i = 0; $i < count($_SESSION['info']); $i++) {
  foreach($_SESSION['info'][$i] as $days => $rental){
    echo '<p>' . $days . '<br>';
    echo $rental . '</p>';
 }
} 
}
?>

<form action="#" method="post">
   Number of Days: <input type="text" name="days" value=""><br/>
   Rental rate: <input type="text" name="rental" value=""><br/>
   <input type="submit" name="add_rental_rate" value="Add Rental Rate">
</form>
```

You should read some docs about session:

> http://php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php

Comment: thanks but I know it can be done  by session, I'm just curious if PHP array alone can do it.

Comment: thanks for clearing my doubt. Now I can use session.